# .htaccess, check if RewriteRule Regex exists as a file or dir

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In order to check if a file eixists (does not exist), I'll write something like that

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((en|es|de)/)?([a-z0-9\+_-]+)/?$ something.php?hl=$2&seoq=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

This works great, **BUT** how do I check if the file exists **based on the result variables** of the RewriteRule.

--

Example:

```
RewriteCond $3 -f (???)
RewriteRule ^((en|es|de)/)?(.*) $3?hl=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

--

**What does/should it do?**

Whenever a file, e.g. **/en/subdir**/something.jpg, is called in the address bar, the server should look, does **/subdir**/something.jpg exist (please note: no subfolder /en!)

The same should happen for directories. Conclusion: if $3 [= (.*) in the RewriteRule] exists as a file or directory, it should show this file or directory, else ignore. How can this be done?

Comment: Digging through the documentation, I found that there is a difference between -f and -F, so this could be the solution, am I right?
`RewriteCond $3 -F [OR]
RewriteCond $3 -d
RewriteRule ^((de|at)/)?(.*) $3?hl=$2 [QSA,L,NC]`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^((en|es|de)/)?(.*)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%3 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%3 !-d
RewriteRule ^((en|es|de)/)?([a-z0-9\+_-]+)/?$ something.php?hl=$2&seoq=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```